# How to stop the int main(void) printf statements when there is an else statement in another function that gives another result?

Tags: c

So everything works in the program so far how the teacher wants it too. However, when I enter 0 for num2 it executes the printf like I want it too, but it also executes the printf at the end of the main. Is there anyway to stop it from also executing the one at end int main when I enter 0? I apologize if my code sucks. This is my first year(semester actually) coding and the teacher doesn't really teach us and I've been learning from the book

```
#include <stdio.h>

//Program with 3 functions 1) Divides 2) Multiplies 3) Calls the other functions

float multiply(float num1, float num2);   
float divide(float num1, float num2);   
void math_call(float num1,float num2);

int main(void){   
    float num1;
    float num2;
    //printf/scanf allows you to choose values for the functions
    printf("Please enter 2 numbers:\n"); 
    scanf("%f", &num1);
    scanf("%f", &num2);
    //printf below calls functions so it can print out your results
    printf("Division = %f  Multiplication = %f", divide(num1, num2), multiply(num1, num2));
    return(0);
}

//Calls function 1 and 2  
void math_call(float num1,float num2){  
    divide(num1,num2);  
    multiply(num1, num2);  
}  

//Divides the arguments and doesn't allow to divide by zero   
float divide(float num1, float num2){   
    if(num2 != 0){     
        float divide;    
        divide = num1/num2;      
        return divide;     
    }    
    else{     
        printf("You can't divide by zero. So your answer for division is undefined.\n");     
        return(0);
    }     
}     

//multiplies the arguments    
float multiply(float num1, float num2){     
if(num2 != 0){    
float multiply;     
multiply = num1*num2;    
return multiply;         
}     
else{      
    printf("If you multiply by zero you will always get zero.\n");     
    return(0);}     
}
```

**This is the result**

```
Please enter 2 numbers:    
4    
0     
If you multiply by zero you will always get zero.    
You can't divide by zero. So your answer for division is undefined.    
Division = 0.000000  Multiplication = 0.000000   
RUN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1s)
```

Comment: Why shouldn't it execute the last printf? You told it to. There is no check in place by you to stop it.

Comment: you could `exit(0)` when such a case occurs.

Comment: Save and check the return value of the function calls before calling the `printf` in `main`. That requires that the functions return something to differentiate between error and an actual result.

Comment: Life saver with the exit(0) just had to add #include <stdlib.h>, thank you so much!

Comment: Note that calling `exit` is ok and will work fine for your exact example. But it's not common to do it that way because most programs won't want to exit immediately on an error condition but take other action such as re-prompt the user for input (wouldn't be surprised if that is the next task you are asked to do).

Comment: So i'm trying to do what you said by reprompt for input, but when I do it doesn't go back to divide or multiply. It automatically  results in getting the last part of the result. Is there anyway to make it return back to divide/multiply after reprompt?

Comment: I think your concept is not very good. Calling `divide` and `multiply` in a `printf` is neither very nice nor practical. What about call these two functions before `printf` like 
`float divResult = divide(num1, num2);` 
`float mulResult = multiply(num1, num2);`
`if(num2 != 0) printf("Division = %f  Multiplication = %f", divResult, mulResult);}` ?

Comment: So place mult/div functions before main? What about the void? Not sure the teacher just told us the shell of the program started with main, void, mult/div. like I have it. Would show a picture, but can't in comments.

Comment: not functions and not before main. I told call of functions before last printf in main.

Comment: I got that to also work, thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this in your code

```
//printf below calls functions so it can print out your results
printf("Division = %f  Multiplication = %f", divide(num1, num2), multiply(num1, num2));
```

Rewrite it as below

```
// call your functions here and fill variables with results
float divResult = divide(num1, num2);
float mulResult = multiply(num1, num2);

// check if num2 is not zero    
if(num2 != 0)
{
    // if it isn't it will print your message
    printf("Division = %f  Multiplication = %f", divResult, mulResult);
}
```